# progress percentage display using Sout in multi-threaded program Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I am validating a set of URLs (Let's say 10K URLs) and right now I've implemented  by validating URLs asynchronously with thread size of 10.

My requirement is to print the progress in percentage of completion and I am achieving it by below code,

```
   //display progress after validation
            System.out.print("\r" + index + "/" + totalUrlsToValidate + "(" + calculatePercentage(index, totalUrlsToValidate) + "%)");
```

**Output:**

**Start time = 2020-01-07 11:01:31.305
Progress : 
4490/4490(100%)**

Problem now is I am implementing nested threading to improve performance rather than increasing thread size, because increasing the thread size didn't improve performance.
Hence I have modified the code to improve performance by splitting 10K URLs into 5 chunks(2K each) and validating the same thing. 
Now my progress display is not shown properly because \r is overriding by each thread and I couldn't see the progress of all threads. Need help here to solve this problem and also display the progress of all 5 chunks simultaneously.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question as the description of the actual problem is quite short but I suspect your problem lies in writing the output from the worker threads themselves. Instead have a separate thread (might be the main thread) periodically check the status of the worker threads and update _all_ progress logs at once.

Comment: You must synchronize the print

Comment: @Thomas, you got it right that I am in deed printing the output from worker threads. I will try to print it outside the worker thread.. thanks for your comment..

Comment: @MauricePerry, Thanks for your reply. synchronized did worked for other souts but sout with /r still has same problem. Its overriding from different threads.